# Как назвать не имеющего привязанности к одной профессии и месту человека?

Tags: терминология

Он не имеет определённой профессии, потому что делает сегодня одно, а завтра — другое. Например, он может работать и изучать пару лет работу в баре, а потом резко поменять вид деятельности, так как старое перестаёт быть интересным.

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от точки зрения, от отношения к такому человеку (позитивного или не очень) или от контекста: **универсал** (многое умеет - и швец, и жнец, и на дуде игрец), **баловень судьбы** (живёт легко, время от времени меняет профессию), человек **без определённого рода занятий** (была даже формальная аббревиатура БОРЗ), **разнорабочий** (по жизни, толком не выучился ни одной профессии).

Answer (score 0):

Человека без корней и больших привязанностей, который с легкостью бросает одно занятие и переключается на другое, часто называют "перекати-поле". По многим причинам такого человека ничего не держит. Он скиталец или по натуре, или по причине нескладных обстоятельств. Ему не сидится на месте, он легко срывается в новый путь.